# I am making a quiz game in Ruby, there is a testing method which checks answers and awards scores, I get this error #<Question:0x0000022164ee9210>

Tags: ruby

I am getting this error `#<Question:0x0000022164ee9210>`, as of my knowledge there is nothing wrong with the code.

```
prompt1 =  "Roses are what, \n a) Blue ,\n b) Red \n c)Orrange"
prompt2 =  "Voilets are what, \n a) Blue ,\n b) Red \n c)Orrange"
prompt3 =  "I love who ?, \n a)Them ,\n b) everyone \n c)You"
```

This is the questions classs

```
class Question 
  attr_accessor :prompt, :answer
  def initialize(prompt,answer)
    @prompt = prompt
    @answer = answer 
  end
  
end
questions = [
  Question.new(prompt1,"b"),
  Question.new(prompt2, "a"),
  Question.new(prompt3,"c")

]
```

This is the testing function that will check the answer.
and display results.

```
def testing (questions)
  answer = ""
  score = 0
  for question in questions
    puts question
    answer = gets.chomp()
    if answer == question.answer
      score +=1 
    end
  end
  puts "\n You got #{score} questions right. out of #{questions.length} questions. "
end

testing(questions)
```

Comment: _"I am getting this error"_ – to me it looks like an internal representation of an object. Why do you think this is an error?

Comment: BTW, `Question` might be slightly misleading because it's not just the actual question but also the options and the correct answer. In multiple-choice test terminology that's usually called "item".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the output of `puts question`.

Replace that by `print question.prompt`

Comment: You are proposing two changes: replacing `puts` by `print` and replacing `question` by `question.prompt`. Are both changes necessary?

Answer (score 2):

There's no error in your code. What you see is the default behavior of printing a custom object via `puts`.

Here's why – calling `puts` prints the given object(s) to stdout using these simple rules, according to [`IO#puts`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> - String: writes the string.
> - Neither string nor array: writes `object.to_s`.
> - Array: writes each element of the array; arrays may be nested.

Since your object is neither a string nor an array, `puts` calls its `to_s` method.

Custom classes (like your `Question` class) by default have `Object` as their superclass. This means that they inherit all methods from `Object`, including [`Object#to_s`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Object.html#method-i-to_s) which:

> [...] prints the object’s class and an encoding of the object id.

Unfortunately, the wording is a little misleading. `to_s` doesn't actually *print* anything, it merely *returns* a string.

However, this string is exactly what you are seeing in `#<Question:0x0000022164ee9210>` – `Question` is your object's class and `0x0000022164ee9210` is the encoded object id.

If you want `puts question` to output something else, for example its `prompt`, you can override `to_s` in your class:

```
class Question
  # ...

  def to_s
    prompt
  end
end
```

The above would result in:

```
question = Question.new("Roses are ...\n a) Blue\n b) Red\n c) Orange", "b")
puts question
```

Output:

```
Roses are ...
 a) Blue
 b) Red
 c) Orange
```

When implementing `to_s`, keep in mind that it is supposed to just return a string. It should not print anything by itself, i.e. do *not* call `puts` inside `to_s`.